# how can i hook every system call a process makes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-calls

I am creating a sandboxing program and trying to hook every single system call a process makes. So far in  my program I am using inline hooking & win32 functions and the scope of my hooks is win32 c++ functions and c# functions (such as CreateFileA, socket.send, etc). However I am trying to increase the scope of my project by intercepting every system call a process makes.

When I first started researching it I encountered the KiFastSystemCall function in ntdll.dll for example
[this article](https://www.malwaretech.com/2015/04/intercepting-all-system-calls-by.html) explaining how to hook it. But as you might have noticed written in the article -

> KiFastSystemCall hooking only works on x86 systems and doesn’t work on Windows 8 or above

So if anyone is aware of a new method of hooking **every** system call a process makes, I'll appreciate it a lot.

Comment: There's a **lot** of Windows system calls.  Why would you want to do this?  Search the internet for "Windows API Charles Petzold" for a good book about the Windows API.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The Win32 API is two layers above the system call interface. I wonder how learning about the Win32 API helps in solving the problem of hooking system calls into the kernel. Mind to expand on that?

Comment: @IInspectable:  The Win32 API will give an idea of the multitude of APIs available and perhaps which ones to hook into.  I don't know of any source that lists only the system and kernel calls.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Clearly the OP is trying to get as close to the kernel boundary as possible, and ideally have a *single* function hooked that dispatches **all** calls into the kernel. Knowing how many Win32 APIs there are isn't part of the solution to that problem.

Comment: @IInspectable you are correct, there are thousands of functions and i want to be able to hook the entry point to the kernel (where the system call is being made) and by that hook every function that opens a file, sends a packet, etc.